# Am I protected from MySQL injection when I am using $this->data?

Tags: mysql, security, cakephp-2.0

I am new to cakephp and security.  I have read that security is built in for protection from MySQL injection if you follow cake's conventions, but can someone tell me if my save() will be safe without manually calling the Security class?

```
function edit($id) {
 $this->set('title', 'Edit your property');
 $this->Unit->id = $id;    
 if (empty($this->data)) {        
$this->data = $this->Unit->read();    
} else { 

    if ($this->Unit->saveAll($this->data)) {            
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your property has been updated.');            

        }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP will quote the data for you. Unless you are using a method similar to:

```
$this_year = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-1 year'));

$this->Baker->updateAll(
    array('Baker.approved' => true),
    array('Baker.created <=' => $this_year)
);
```

which takes SQL literals, you are safe and must *not* quote the data yourself to avoid getting the quotes in the data. Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Comment: as a user stated below, what about my parameter?

Comment: Yes, if by parameter you mean $id in the code snippet. If you want to convince yourself 100% you can do one (or both!) of the following: Follow CakePHP's code to see what it does with $id, or do some debugging and put in a value that would be invalid if not escaped (e.g. run with $id = "12';") and see if you get a SQL error.

Answer (score 3):

Cake escapes the data IF you use the db-funcitons of cake (like $this->modelname->save($this->data) or $this->find(..)), be aware that if you use custom queries like $this->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '.$this->data['model']['id']); cake will NOT escape them, keep that in mind!

Comment: Thank you! Had to give credit to the first answer, he got here first.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help and keep you from saving un-escaped data into the datase   ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I will say **no** as your parameter is not specialised or sanitized anywhere. Something like this, would limit the risk

```
function edit($id) { 
   // type cast the id to be forced into number and check if $id has greater than 1 
   if((int)$id > 0) {

   // hence the injection vulnerability at $id is fixed
   //....remaining part
   }
}
```

Comment: PHP does only support [limited type hinting for object and array type](http://php.net/language.oop5.typehinting).

Comment: @Gumbo, I guess, i mixed [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) with type hinting. I hope it should do be ok now

Comment: This still allows negative integers.

Comment: @Gumbo, boy you are one tough customer. Now, throw me a +1. I think I earned it.

Comment: No, definitely not. Because the question scope is quite specific (CakePHP 2.0) but you did only give a general answer. What if CakePHP 2.0 already does protect against SQL injections? [As @Achamenes mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9538919/53114), having a model to represent the data in PHP indicates that CakePHP does proper type conversion.

Comment: @Gumbo, Framework over simple PHP technique. Ok, if thats what OP wants, then I dont have anything to say.

Comment: @Starx, this IS good advice when outside of the Cakephp framework and I will keep it in mind for future PHP work.

Comment: @Gumbo, I definitely see your points, and I can see that I would need to build upon his code to protect myself.